# Flutter: How to change border color in disabled TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can't change border color, when Textfield disabled.

**Decoration Settings**

```
const textshowad = InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Title',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0,top: 20.0,right: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple,width: 2.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(15, 15)),
    ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
));
```

**Textfield**

```
 TextFormField(
          decoration: textshowad,
        enabled: false,
        initialValue: widget.titletext,
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 'disabledBorder' parameter in InputDecoration.

```
const textshowad = InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Title',
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0,top: 20.0,right: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple,width: 2.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(15, 15)),
    ),
     disabledBorder : OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey,width: 2.0),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(15, 15)),
    ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ternary operators for this purpose. See the below code for better understanding.

```
bool isEnabled=false;

const textshowad = InputDecoration(
  labelText: 'Title',
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0,top: 20.0,right: 20.0,bottom: 20.0),
  border: isEnabled 
    ? OutlineInputBorder(...) 
    : OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple,width: 2.0),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(15, 15)),
  ),
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
));

...

TextFormField(
  decoration: textshowad,
  enabled: isEnabled,
  initialValue: widget.titletext,
),
```